# Difference in "fields eclosed by" and "fields optionally escaped by"

Tags: mysql, select, select-into-outfile

In MySQL there are two options for the `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` command:

```
--fields-enclosed-by=char
--fields-optionally-enclosed-by=char
```

What's the basic difference in these two options?

Enclosed by means forcefully all fields are escaped by given char but what in case of optionally? How MySQL take care of this option ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is what [MySQL manual says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) (I don't know why they put it in `LOAD DATA`):

> if you omit the word `OPTIONALLY`, all fields are enclosed by the
>   `ENCLOSED BY` character.
>
> ...
>
> If you specify `OPTIONALLY`, the `ENCLOSED BY`
>   character is used only to enclose values from columns that have a
>   string data type (such as `CHAR`, `BINARY`, `TEXT`, or `ENUM`)

In reality, also `TIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, `DATE` and `DATETIME` values are enclosed when `OPTIONALLY` is specified.